# Syntax of sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have one file on server "dailyconfig.yml" which contains line as follows

```
logFiles: ["responseActions.csv.2015-04-24","responseActions.csv.2015-04-25","responseActions.csv.2015-04-26"]
```

I have to change the date of each file by using sed command.

My script is as follows.

```
echo -n "Enter first date (format: YYYY-mm-dd): "
read startDate
echo "startDate outside loop: $startDate"
echo -n "Enter last date (format: YYYY-mm-dd): "
read endDate
echo "endDate outside loop: $endDate"
d1=$(date -d "$endDate" +%s)
echo "d1 = $d1"
d2=$(date -d "$startDate" +%s)
echo "d2 = $d2"
datediff=$(($(((d1-d2)/86400))+1)) 
echo "datediff = $datediff"
count=1
echo "count outside loop: $count"
while test $count -le $datediff 
do
echo "count=$count"
echo "datediff=$datediff"
echo "Entered in loop"
date1=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$startDate -1 day"`
echo "date1 = $date1"
date2=`date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$startDate +1 day"`
echo "date2 = $date2"
sed -i "s/startDate:.*18:30:00/startDate: $date1 18:30:00/g" configdaily.yml
sed -i "s/endDate:.*18:30:00/endDate: $startDate 18:30:00/g" configdaily.yml
**sed -i "s/logFiles:*]/logFiles: [\"responseActions.csv.$date1\",\"responseActions.csv.$startDate\",\"responseActions.csv.$date2\"]/g" configdaily.yml**
sleep 10
startDate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$startDate +1 day")
echo " startDate inside loop: $startDate"
count=$((count+1))
echo "count inside loop: $count"

done
```

In above script you can see three sed command, out of which third sed command does not give required output.

Therefore kindly suggest the proper syntax or changes in third sed command.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? What does happen?

Comment: I already mentioned in question that there is a one line in my dailyconfig.yml file as follows

logFiles: ["responseActions.csv.2015-04-24","responseActions.csv.2015-04-25","responseActions.csv.2015-04-26"]

I need to replace dates in this line iteratively in while loop.

and for those date you can see date calculation in my script.

Note: All that echo part in script is just for confirming whether date is processed appropriately and loop is working fine or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using `logfiles:*` where probably you mean `logfiles:.*`.  The expression `:*` means zero or more repetitions of the literal colon character.  The expression `.*` means zero or more repetitions of any character (notice also how `.` is a metacharacter which matches any single character except newline).

Tangentially, running three successive `sed` scripts on the same file is somewhat wasteful.  You should be able to combine them into a single script:

```
sed -i -e "s/startDate:.*18:30:00/startDate: $date1 18:30:00/" \
       -e "s/endDate:.*18:30:00/endDate: $startDate 18:30:00/" \
       -e "s/logFiles:.*]/logFiles: [\"responseActions.csv.$date1\",\"responseActions.csv.$startDate\",\"responseActions.csv.$date2\"]/" configdaily.yml
```

I also removed the `/g` flag on all of these, as it would appear impossible for any of your patterns to match more than once on the same line.  The meaning of `g` is to repeat matching on the same line when there are multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "
   s#startDate:.*18:30:00#startDate: ${date1} 18:30:00#g
   s#endDate:.*18:30:00#endDate: $startDate 18:30:00#g
   s#logFiles:*]#logFiles: [\"responseActions.csv.${date1}\",\"responseActions.csv.${startDate}\",\"responseActions.csv.${date2}\"]#g" configdaily.yml
```

- action could be separate by new line or `;` or eventually in several `-e "Action"`
- i use othjer separator than `/` because date and file name could use this but it's not mandatory if no `/` is inside variable content or pattern
- `g` is optional becasue it treat only 1 occurence per line